# pandas dataframe groups check the number of unique values of a column is one but exclude empty strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
id    invoice_no
1     6636
1     6637
2     6639
2     6639
3     
3    
4     6635
4     6635
4     6635
```

the `invoice_no` for `id` 3 are all empty strings or spaces; I want to

```
df['same_invoice_no'] = df.groupby("id")["invoice_no"].transform('nunique') == 1
```

but also consider spaces and empty string `invoice_no` in each group as `same_invoice_no = False`; I am wondering how to do that. The result will look like,

```
id    invoice_no    same_invoice_no
1     6636          False
1     6637          False
2     6639          True
2     6639          True
3                   False
3                   False
4     6635          True
4     6635          True
4     6635          True
```

Comment: just convert to `float` so `nan` will be `False`

Comment: as you know np.nan == np.nan is False. You want to treat null values as equal to each other, so why not just use `fillna(-99)` or some other meaningless value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty strings equate to True but NaNs don't. Replace empty strings by Numpy nan

```
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace = True)
df['same_invoice_no'] = df.groupby("id")["invoice_no"].transform('nunique') == 1

    id  invoice_no  same_invoice_no
0   1   6636.0      False
1   1   6637.0      False
2   2   6639.0      True
3   2   6639.0      True
4   3   NaN         False
5   3   NaN         False
6   4   6635.0      True
7   4   6635.0      True
8   4   6635.0      True
```